# How to pass a list asks a parameter in odeint in Python?

Tags: python

I'm new to Python, and I'm graphing Energy versus time. I would like to graph several plots with different epsilon values eg. epsl = [0, 0.3, 0.02, 0.05].  is there a way to pass a list of different epsilon values through odeint and graph them? The code below shows for one value of epsl at 0.05.

```html
def position(x,t, epsl):
    dx = np.zeros(2)
    # E(t) = 1/2mv^2 + 1/2kx^2
    # E(t)_bar = x_bar^2 + v_bar^2
    ko = 1                         
    omega = 2         
    k = ko*(1-epsl*np.cos(omega*t))
    dx[0] = x[1]
    dx[1] = -k*x[0]
    return dx

# initial conditions
ic=[1,1]

# make a list for epsl values
epsl = 0.05 

#time points
t = np.linspace(0, 200, 100000)

#solve ODE
ksoln = odeint(position, ic, t, args=(epsl,))

# Energy
Kenergy=ksoln[:,0]**2+ksoln[:,1]**2 

plt.plot(t, Kenergy)
plt.xlabel('t')
plt.title('Energy')
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can plot multiple lines on one plot. Try something like this:

```
def position(x,t, epsl):
    dx = np.zeros(2)
    # E(t) = 1/2mv^2 + 1/2kx^2
    # E(t)_bar = x_bar^2 + v_bar^2
    ko = 1                         
    omega = 2         
    k = ko*(1-epsl*np.cos(omega*t))
    dx[0] = x[1]
    dx[1] = -k*x[0]
    return dx

# initial conditions
ic=[1,1]

# make a list for epsl values
epsls = [0, 0.3, 0.02, 0.05]

#time points
t = np.linspace(0, 200, 100000)

#solve ODE
ksolns = [odeint(position, ic, t, args=(epsl,)) for epsl in epsls]

# Energy
Kenergys = [ksoln[:,0]**2+ksoln[:,1]**2 for kslon in kslons]

[plt.plot(t, Kenergy) for Kenergy in Kenergys]
plt.xlabel('t')
plt.title('Energy')
plt.show()
```

Comment: Thank you so much, it worked perfectly! For anyone who puts this code back in, there's two type in the ling of Kenergys=...., it should be "Kenergys = [ksoln[:,0]**2+ksoln[:,1]**2 for ksoln in ksolns]"